# Load next result from query in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to load the next result from a query when there is a limit?

For example, if I want to load 5 users from `query.limit(5)`, is there a way to load the next 5 users from the same query? If so, would this be done in Javascript(where my query is) or Objective-C(where the query is called from)? I couldn't find anything in the Parse docs either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Parse does not have mechanism to directly provide *next* operation. Instead, you should take a look at the `skip` property. It skips the certain numbers of objects before querying.

For your case, you can implement the formula `skip = 5 * (# of request - 1)`. It means that your `skip` property should be assigned 5 after the first request, then make another request to implement the *next* operation.

Comment: My only problem with this, is that skip will skip the first X users no matter what. And doing `query.skip(5 * (numberOfRequests - 1));` where numberOfRequests is equal to 1, it will end up skipping 0 people. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If skip is 0, then it does not skip. Will query from the beginning.